# How to generate cookie (in ASP.NET Core Web Application) and send it to frontend

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have 2 projects (asp.net core web app) and react.js. I am calling an endpoint with react (login) and want to get the cookie. I am not sure if the methods in the startup class are all ok.

This is the react call.

```
handleLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    fetch('https://localhost:5001/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      credentials: "same-origin"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data)
          history.push('/home');
      });
  }
```

This is the endpoint

```
[Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
            if (user != null)
            {

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return new JsonResult(true, new JsonSerializerSettings());
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult(false, new JsonSerializerSettings());
        }
```

This is the Startup.ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 5001;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            // services.AddSession();
            services.AddSession(opts =>
            {
                opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(enableCors, builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
        }
```

And this is the Startup.Configure

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCors(enableCors);
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error somewhere or something? This question is curently too general... "Can you look around and see if there is anything that jumps out at you?" seems to be what you are asking and isn't really a good starting point. Can you show a minimal reproducable example of whatever the issue is? If that isn't what you are asking, can you clarify? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no error, I execute the request, the user successfully logs in and then there is no cookie, because I don't know how to extract it from userManager or signInManager and pass it as a response to the react request

Comment: i noticed you had `app.UseAuthentication();` declared. hence, i dont think you login with the good old cookies. [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header perhaps?